# Как добавить свои custom классы?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Привет есть такой код от WooCommerce

```
<div <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

Простой див а php отвечает за вывод классов. Как к этим классам добавить свой кастомный?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div <?php post_class('custom-class'); ?> <?php post_class(); ?> >
```

Answer (score 0):

Второй вариант добавления классов - использование хука (фильтра) внутри functions.php активной темы:

```
<?php
/**
 * Добавляем свои классы к посту
 */
function mihdan_add_classes( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    foreach( ( get_the_category( $post->ID ) ) as $category )
        $classes[] = $category->category_nicename;
        return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'mihdan_add_classes' );
```